# HTML <noscript> tag does not work

Tags: html

Per definition `<noscript>` should show the text inside it if Javascript is disabled.

I used IE11 and disabled JavaScript to only see a blank page come up with no message at all.

```
<head>
<noscript>Javascript is disabled!</noscript>
<script>document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Script Enabled";</script>    
</head>
<p id="demo"> Test</p>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the html surrounding this snippet?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: `noscript` belongs i nthe body section, not the head; but this probably won't fix your problem, unfortunately.

Comment: whoops, i'm not exactly correct, but you should read [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/the-noscript-element.html).

Comment: Maybe the script is running and throwing an error because you're looking for an element that doesn't exist yet. Did you look in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page works for me *if javascript is disabled*: It prints the "javascript is disabled" message at the top.

But if I enabled it, does not change the "Test" text, because the script is executed *before* the page is loaded. And even if it was loaded, there is no `<body>`, so `document.getElementById` will return `null`.

A working correction could be this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<noscript>Javascript is disabled!</noscript>
<script>window.onload=function(){document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Script Enabled";}</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"> Test</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: interesting. Did you use chrome?

Comment: Yes. Tested in IE11 and Chrome. The same behaviour in both, and my solution works in both.

Comment: technically noscript can be placed in head but when done so is limited https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp  "When used inside the <head> element: <noscript> must contain only <link>, <style>, and <meta> elements."  (So, i think, no text, so often not ideal)

Comment: saying the page works for you is rsky cos it just so happens that that one does, but if the noscript tag had e.g. <noscript>aaa</noscript> it would fail because it is in head and is limited in head

Comment: this answer is very wrong to put text within noscript within head, and if it worked it was a fluke, see https://superuser.com/questions/1419742/in-firefox-why-is-this-page-rendered-this-waycontents-of-noscript-tag-getting/1453689#1453689  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452065/in-html-webpage-the-content-within-noscript-tags-are-not-getting-rendered-by-br

Answer (score 2):

From what you have told us above, it seems as if you have entered/used the correct syntax.

I tried it in Chrome 47 and works fine, maybe try it in different browsers and see your results OR make sure you have actually turned off JavaScript.

**Example:**

```js
<script>
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

*From W3Schools - [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)*

You could always do this too:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#noscript-description').css({
    'display' : 'none'
    
    // Just change the none to block to see the results
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="noscript-description">This can be seen if you <b>DO NOT</b> have JavaScript enabled.</p>
    <!-- I have added in jQuery, if you never realised -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the noscript tag inside the body tag

Comment: technically noscript can be placed in head but when done so is limited https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp  "When used inside the <head> element: <noscript> must contain only <link>, <style>, and <meta> elements."  (So, i think, no text, so often not ideal)

Comment: so yes it should, even must, go in the body, but only because it contains text. And so indeed the currently accepted answer is wrong and it only works by fluke

Answer (score 0):

There an issue with the placement of your `<script>` tags and an issue with the placement of your `<noscript>abc</noscript>` tags.

A) For your `<script>` tag to function correctly it should run after the body not before. (Or if put before the body then some extra code to make sure it waits for the window or DOM to load i.e. what littlesanti did with window.onload)

B) For  `<noscript>abc</noscript>` tags to run correctly, they should be within the body, since they contain text.